# HadoopDashboard is not created after HDInsight installation

Tags: hadoop, installation, web-platform-installer, azure-hdinsight

This is the 2nd day I am trying to install HDInsight in my dev machine. I had installed it some months back and there was no problem. One day things stopped working and I could see that the app pools are not getting started due to issues related to .\hadoop account.

So I uninstalled and installed again. The problem starts from there. I can't see the Hadoop dash board in IIS. I tried in offline mode of WebPI too.

Interesting thing I could see in offline mode is the downloaded size of MSSingleNodeInstaller.msi is 3.8 MB. When I checked the size of HDINSIGHT-PREVIEW  in http://www.microsoft.com/web/webpi/4.5/toolsproductlist.xml it shows around 30 MB.

After installation C:\HadoopFeaturePackSetup\Packages folder doesn't contain the files HadoopWebApi-winpkg.zip & HadoopDashboard-winpkg.zip

Please give a solution which doesn't require hard disk formatting or trying out in a new machine. I can also upload the logs if required.

Thanks in Advance

Joy

Answer (score 0):

I was able to execute Map Reduce tasks without the help of hadoop dashboard site and WebAPI web application. Just executed my Visual Studio project and its running :) May be I will struck at some other point due to lack of dashboard and web api. I can see the status of the Hadoop Map-Reduce tasks in job tracker site http://localhost:50030/jobtracker.jsp].